# Github guest branch and password protected branches

Tags: git

Is it possible to share projects that are using git with for example dropbox and provide a default branch for new users of the code so they don't mess up the code I've written beforehand? I also would like to know if it's possible to password-protect certain branches in git? Thanks for any help!

Comment: You can restrict merge rights in certain branches. That only allows you to review the code before merging yourself. But, if the restriction has a loop hole then the unauthorised person can push the code without any restrictions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to share projects that are using git with for example dropbox...

Yes, although you have to have a really good reason why you are using dropbox over cloning a project and having that project in a remote repo. Keep in mind that if you don't have a remote repo and will just share a git project over some other method, although quite ironic, you will loose on a lot of functionality from git.

> ... and provide a default branch for new users of the code so they don't mess up the code I've written beforehand

You can always setup a default branch for anyone from your own project and then share it. As for the part where they don't mess with your code... I would assume that since you are sharing your project through dropbox, you don't want the other people to make changes to your other branches and your other code. You can have branch restrictions for merging, as said in the comments, but then again, if you don't have a remote, you can't really make use of said restrictions. But what you **do** have is `git hooks`. You can setup a `pre-commit` hook, which can check if people have made changes to any branch or file you don't want it to change. Read more about git hooks [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks).

> I also would like to know if it's possible to password-protect certain branches in git?

Unless you are using some other system to work with git, like [gitolite](https://gitolite.com/gitolite/), then you can't just have password protected branches. I would assume you can mimic such behavior with git-hooks again.